# Php foreach date

Tags: php, sql, date, foreach

I got this:

```
foreach($result_set_cw_01 as $result_cw_01) {

    $newcw = mt_rand(1, 52);

    $week = $newcw;
    $year = date("Y");
    $time = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year) + ($week * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $time = $time - ((date('N', $time) - 1) * 24 * 60 * 60);

    $startWeek = date('Y-d-M', $time);
    $endWeek = date('Y-d-M', $time + (6 * 24 * 60 * 60));

    # Insert Random Calender Week
    $set = array(
                'calender_week' => $week,
                'start_week' => $startWeek,
                'end_week' => $endWeek,
                );

    $whereWeek = array('id = :id');
    $valuesWeek = array('id' => $result_cw_01['id']);

    $db->update($table, $set, $whereWeek, $valuesWeek);
}
```

Let me explain what happens.
I got a database with ids, users, names, calender_week, start_week and end_week.

I basically get a random number between 1 and 52 with this line

> $newcw = mt_rand(1, 52);

It stands for calender week.

The next lines does calculate the starting day (monday) and the ending day (sunday) of that week for each number I have.

Next I insert and update my new values into my database.

Now what does not work is the update on `$startWeek` and `$endweek` into my database.

If I echo out `$result_cw_01['calender_week']` I get the `$startWeek` and `$endweek` of the last user's calenderweek.

But if I echo `$startWeek` and `$endWeek` I get the correct date for that specific calenderweek, but it just does not save it properly.

Can anyone help.

I changed update to select and echod it:
$db->update($table, $set, $whereWeek, $valuesWeek);

$db->select($table, $set, $whereWeek, $valuesWeek);

```
string 'SELECT 2,2015-01-12,2015-01-18 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=57)

string 'SELECT 49,2015-12-07,2015-12-13 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=58)

string 'SELECT 26,2015-06-29,2015-07-05 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=58)

string 'SELECT 11,2015-03-16,2015-03-22 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=58)

string 'SELECT 11,2015-03-16,2015-03-22 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=58)

string 'SELECT 51,2015-12-21,2015-12-27 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=58)

string 'SELECT 39,2015-09-28,2015-10-04 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=58)

string 'SELECT 9,2015-03-02,2015-03-08 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=57)

string 'SELECT 2,2015-01-12,2015-01-18 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=57)

string 'SELECT 25,2015-06-22,2015-06-28 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=58)

string 'SELECT 24,2015-06-15,2015-06-21 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=58)

string 'SELECT 7,2015-02-16,2015-02-22 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=57)

string 'SELECT 18,2015-05-04,2015-05-10 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=58)

string 'SELECT 27,2015-07-06,2015-07-12 FROM staff  where id = :id' (length=58)
```

Comment: echo your previously executed query ans check what query is getting generated.

Comment: which query? confused

Comment: echo  $db->update($table, $set, $whereWeek, $valuesWeek); gives me 0

Comment: ill edit question to format this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you shouldn't use format 'Y-d-M' but 'Y-m-d'

Comment: this is the key for the solution I think thanks alot